# Silverlight, How I Can Use OnClick Behavior On Extended Button Component?

Tags: silverlight, button, components

I create new class which extend Button component in silverlight, because I need to animate trough method OnLeftMouseDown and OnLeftMouseUp, it works, but now onClick is not working for the component, here is my class:

```
public class ExtendedButton : Button
{
    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //running storyboard
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //running storyboard
    }
}
```

I already add OnClick on that component but it's not work, how I can use OnClick behavior as usual button?

Regards,
Imam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely you have failed to call the base methods, its from these events that the underlying button determines when to fire click so if you don't call them it won't happen:

```
public class ExtendedButton : Button 
{ 
    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
    { 
        //running storyboard
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e) 
    } 

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
    { 
        //running storyboard
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(e); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi anthony, 

Thank you for the answer, yes indeed, I think when we extend the button object, we cannot used event onClick anymore, now in my application I use onMouseLeftButtonDown and onLeftMouseButtonUp events, without using onClick anymore.

I also mark your answer as my thread answer, thanks again.

Regards,

Imam